# How to make a web server respond to a request outside the local network?

Tags: python, linux, http, curl, webserver

I've set up a web server on a Linux machine on port 8000, using:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

If I run `curl -XGET '127.0.0.1:8000'` I get a response. But if I try accessing it on a browser in a different machine using `http://domain:8000`, I get no response.

How can I make it work outside the local network?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to Local Web Server when I am Outside my LAN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404699/connecting-to-local-web-server-when-i-am-outside-my-lan)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add port redirect from your router (adsl modem, switch, hub) to your computer. Or you can use ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) for such as things.

Comment: You are a saviour.